# How can I adjust my script to use minSL if less than 0.5%?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to implement a set of rules for my stop loss criteria. The rules are:

- set off close of trigger candle
- minimum stop loss percent 0.5%
- if anything less eg. 0.17%, default stop loss of 0.5% is used
- otherwise, if greater than 0.5%, leave it

With the code below its basically ignoring the variable minSL.

If I re-assign t_stop := with minSL it works perfectly

My question is how do I get my script to use minSL if longStop or shortStop are < than 0.5%?

This is the block of code I'm running for it

``

```
minSL = close - (close * 0.005)


//Calculate stops and targets
longStop         = low - atr
shortStop        = high + atr
longStopDistance = close - longStop
shortStoDistance = shortStop - close
longTarget       = close + (longStopDistance * 3.4)
shortTarget      = close - (shortStoDistance * 3.4)

//Save stops and targets
var t_stop = 0.0
var t_target = 0.0

//Enter our buy order
if buyCondition 
    t_stop := longStop < 0.05 ? minSL : longStop
    t_target := longTarget
    strategy.entry(id = 'Long', direction = strategy.long)


//Enter our sell order
if sellCondition 
    t_stop := shortStop < 0.05 ? minSL : shortStop
    t_target := shortTarget
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short', direction = strategy.short)//here we are asking, is buySignal true? if so, enter our trade using strategy.entry with a id(title), of 'Long' and direction of long

//Manage exit orders
strategy.exit(id = 'Long Exit', from_entry = 'Long', limit = t_target, stop = t_stop, when = strategy.position_size > 0)
strategy.exit(id = 'Short Exit', from_entry = 'Short', limit = t_target, stop = t_stop, when = strategy.position_size < 0)
```

``